# MySQL update not support index condition pushdown?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb

```
CREATE TABLE `t2` (
  `a` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `b` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `d` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `e` text,
  KEY `ii1` (`a`,`b`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

sql1: update t2 set b = 3 where a = 1;
sql2: select b from t2 where a = 1;
```

sql2 will use index condition pushdown, but sql1 doesn't, but why, is that data format between engine and server transformation?

```
mysql> explain select b from t2 where a = 1;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2    | NULL       | ref  | ii1           | ii1  | 5       | const |    1 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain update t2 set b = 3 where a = 1;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+----------+------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+----------+------------------------------+
|  1 | UPDATE      | t2    | NULL       | range | ii1           | ii1  | 5       | const |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using temporary |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+----------+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 3):

The note `Using index` indicates the query is using a covering index. This means the SELECT query can return results by reading only the index. This is not possible with an INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE, because both the index and the table the index belongs to must be updated simultaneously.

The note `Using index condition` is for index condition pushdown. This is the feature of delegating some pre-filtering to the storage engine.

The words in the EXPLAIN output are similar, but these two notes refer to totally different features.

Comment: thanks bill, but I still wonder that why UPDATE will retrieve the whole record before executing the updating? ie. `sql2` can retrieve column `a` and column `b`, but actually `sql2` retrieve column `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` in `read_record`, all columns of the record. It's strange.

Comment: InnoDB stores the whole record together, all columns on the same page. To update any column of it, the whole page must be read into the buffer pool first.

Comment: Thanks Bill, but SELECT will use index condition pushdown, sql1 only retrieve column `a` and column `b`.

Comment: Did you read my answer? `Using index` is not the same as index condition pushdown. The EXPLAIN output you showed does not indicate it is using index condition pushdown.